# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context - AWS Amplify

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, swiftui, aws-amplify

I am learning iOS and amplify and struggling my way through implementing a custom auth flow. I have run into an issue I can't resolve. Here is my code:

```
//
//  SessionManager.swift
//  Mapwork
//
//  Created by James Nebeker on 2/27/21.
//

import Foundation
import Combine
import Amplify
import AmplifyPlugins

enum AuthState {
    case signUp
    case login
    case confirmCode(username:  String)
    case session (user: AuthUser)
    case firstTime
    case confirmSignIn
   
}

final class SessionManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var authState: AuthState = .firstTime
    
    func getCurrentAuthUser() {
        if let user = Amplify.Auth.getCurrentUser() {
            authState = .session(user: user)
        } else {
            authState = .login
        }
    }
    
    func showSignUpView()
    {
        authState = .signUp
    }
    
    func showLoginView()
    {
        authState = .login
    }
    
    func showConfirmationSignInView()
    {
        authState = .confirmSignIn
    }
    
    func signUp(username: String, email: String) {
        let userAttributes = [AuthUserAttribute(.email, value: email)]
        let options = AuthSignUpRequest.Options(userAttributes: userAttributes)
       
        _ = Amplify.Auth.signUp(username: username, password: UUID().uuidString, options: options) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let signUpResult):
                if case let .confirmUser(deliveryDetails, _) = signUpResult.nextStep {
                    print("Delivery details \(String(describing: deliveryDetails))")
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.authState = .confirmCode(username: username)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Signup Complete")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occurred while registering a user \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func confirmSignUp(for username: String, with confirmationCode: String) {
        Amplify.Auth.confirmSignUp(for: username, confirmationCode: confirmationCode) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                print("Confirm signUp succeeded")
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.showLoginView()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occurred while confirming sign up \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func signIn(username: String) {
        Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username) { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                if case .confirmSignInWithCustomChallenge(_) = result.nextStep {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.showConfirmationSignInView()
                    }
                } else {
                    print("Sign in succeeded")
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Sign in failed \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    func customChallenge(response: String) {
        Amplify.Auth.confirmSignIn(challengeResponse: response) {[weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case .success:
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.getCurrentAuthUser()
                }
                print("Confirm sign in succeeded")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Confirm sign in failed \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

In the above code, I have copied this function from the AWS Amplify docs exactly:

```
func signIn(username: String) {
    Amplify.Auth.signIn(username: username) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success:
            if case .confirmSignInWithCustomChallenge(_) = result.nextStep {
                // Ask the user to enter the custom challenge.
            } else {
                print("Sign in succeeded")   
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Sign in failed \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

But I am receiving this error:

```
Type of expression is ambiguous without more context
```

Within the switch statement. I really don't understand this because I have not changed this code, I have copied it directly from the documentation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Specifically, the error is appearing here:

[image: Error on XCode]

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you resolve this?

Comment: For me, I (finally) resolved by cleaning the build folder.